# My xcode 3.1.3 and sdk 3.1 can not do auto synthesize in ios?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am new in ios developer.I am using xcode 3.1.3 and sdk 3.1,but my sdk cannot perform auto synthesize..please help me

Comment: Download XCode6.1. That's the latest version. You'll need this to compile for iOS8. Only then will Apple accept your apps. 3.1 is a very old version.

Comment: thnxxx alot...is thery any alternae solutions???

Comment: I'd suggest you download Xcode 6.1 as 3.1.3 is super old.

Comment: Anil is right, you should update. But if you can't for some crazy reason, what's wrong with just synthesising the properties? With Xcode 3.1.3 you'll also have to use manual reference counting. That should be a way bigger concern than having to synthesise some properties.